# Concatenate Multi index dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, multi-index

,I'm trying to concatenate multiple resultant dataframes together from a function which I have called with tqdm process_map. Each df has one column, one index and 3 sub-indices. When I concat them, the inidces don't align as you can see below. This creates NaN which I would like to avoid.

```
cost_values = pd.concat(process_map(run_simulation_a0_b0_search, param_list, max_workers=4),axis=1)


                           0.01      10.00     0.01      10.00
0.01  Average distance  3.055864  0.423096       NaN       NaN
      Collisions        0.007313  0.000000       NaN       NaN
      Minimum distance  0.867630  0.332057       NaN       NaN
10.00 Average distance       NaN       NaN  0.445388  0.418373
      Collisions             NaN       NaN  0.000906  0.000000
      Minimum distance       NaN       NaN  0.280610  0.297080
```

Here are the 4 dfs printed before they are returned by the `run_simulation_a0_b0_search` function

```
                        0.01
0.01 Collisions        0.0073125
     Average distance    3.05586
     Minimum distance    0.86763


                           10.0
0.01 Collisions               0
     Average distance  0.423096
     Minimum distance  0.332057

                           0.01
10.0 Collisions        0.00090625
     Average distance    0.445388
     Minimum distance     0.28061

                           10.0
10.0 Collisions               0
     Average distance  0.418373
     Minimum distance   0.29708
```

Comment: how can we help without knowing the previous dfs?

Comment: My bad, I just added one as an example

Comment: what's the `process_map` function?

Comment: It similar to pool function from multiprocessing, it allows to multithread

Comment: just provide  the question with 2 or 3 example dataframes. We should be able to copy/paste your example, see your error, and troubleshoot from there

Comment: I've updated with the 4 dfs before they are concatenated, let me know if it's clearer now